# Create a tar.xz file on command line

Tags: windows, compression, tar, xz

How can I compress a tar file into a tar.xz file on Windows?

I converted my folder into a tar file as follows:

1. Selected the file
2. Right-clicked one of the highlighted items
3. Clicked add to archive
4. Choose tar from the archive format drop-down menu

Answer (score 4):

tar is now available natively on Windows 10, just open cmd.exe and you can create a tar.xz file with `tar -cJf <archive.tar.xz> <files>`

Comment: I used Cygwin tar since Windows tar complained about not supporting xz

Answer (score 0):

You can do thease ones
- Download 7zip then pack and unpack zip file
https://www.7-zip.org/

-  Download  Linux subsystem for Windows (MSYS,Cygwin, Virtual Machines)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#enable-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-feature-gui

http://www.cygwin.com/
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys